# OSGi, Jetty and CometD/Bayeux

Tags: jetty, osgi, comet, bayeux

I have got Jetty and Bayeux working well together to allow me to use comet with dojo.  However, I now need to move to an OSGi jetty environment and am struggling to get it working.

In the non-OSGi environment, the following line works and lets me start services etc.  However, in OSGi, there is no attribute "BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE" in the servlet context/config.

```
BayeuxServer bayeux = (BayeuxServer)getServletContext().getAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE);
```

Does anyone have any sample code, blog posts, reference articles etc to help with this?  Googling hasn't resulted in anything!

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: I've got it working after hitting my head on a brick wall for hours and hours!  Writing a blog post about it, will link here when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written up how to do it here - http://www.jellard.co.uk/2011/12/osgi-jetty-cometd-bayeux-and-dojo/

Comment: Hi @Ed Jellard your link does not work anymore. Some comments within the answer would have been nice.